# Best way to know if something isBoolean

Tags: smalltalk

What's the best way to ask an object whether it's a boolean?

As requested, here's the reasons:

I've a method that prints stuff, any kind of stuff, and when this stuff is a boolean I want it to print 'Yes' or 'No' instead of true or false. I was doing it like this, but it looked too much as a hack to me:

```
[anObject
    ifTrue: [ 'Yes' ]
    ifFalse: [ 'No' ] ] 
        on: Error 
        do: [ anObject printString ]
```

Comment: Perhaps if you can explain why you want "to ask an object whether it's a boolean" the experts will be able to suggest something that matches what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your own definition of printString then:

```
Object >> #bernatPrintString
  ^self printString

True >> #bernatPrintString
  ^'Yes'

False >> #bernatPrintString
  ^'No'
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks much more OO

Comment: This is a good solution, however it does not handle recursivity of printString, ('IsBernatPrintingRecursive?' -> false) bernatPrintString.

Answer (score 4):

```
anObject == true or: [ anObject == false ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the most efficient one?

Comment: Yes, this is very efficient. It does not send any messages; it is compiled to a few efficient bytecodes.

Answer (score 2):

`value isKindOf: Boolean` – but I would avoid such checks! Probably there's something a bit wrong if you need to do this...

Comment: Yup, that's what I wanted to avoid :)

Comment: I don't think the point was to avoid this syntax but to avoid the check altogether...

Answer (score 0):

What could be simpler?

anObject isBoolean ifTrue: [ ... ] ifFalse: [ ... ]

Comment: But isBoolean does not exist in every dialect ;)

Answer (score -1):

Even simpler, most efficient and not need to avoid: `value class == Boolean`

Comment: This assume that `true` and `false` both are instances of the Boolean class. But in the usual Smalltalk implementation of booleans `true` is a singleton instance of the `True` class and `false` is a singleton instance of the `False` class. And both these `True` and `Flase` classes inherit from `Boolean`.